# Windows 10 wakes up at night although Update was completely finished a day before

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, hibernate, reboot, wake-up

I really really hate when my computer wakes up at 4:00h in the morning. So when I get Updates for my Win10 x64, I always schedule an immediate reboot, so that the update process can finish. That's what I did yesterday evening. After that, I checked if all updates were actually installed, which was the case.

Nevertheless, Windows in its own kind of magic wisdom decided, to power up my computer in the middle of the night. Looking at event log, it clearly states that "NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot" caused my system to wake up at night. No matter how often I disable that service, Windows reenables it, and although all updates were installed, and a reboot was done the day before, Windows still thinks it needs to wake up.

Why? Can anybody tell me how to reliably prevent Windows from automatically waking up from hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

`Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings\Change advanced power settings`

- Find `Sleep` and click the `+` object
- Find `Allow wake timers` and select `Disable`

Also if `NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot` is enabled, click `Disable`. `UpdateOrchestrator` does not sound like a normal object in Task Scheduler; it may be part of some sort of 3rd party program that is installed on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a command `powercfg -lastwake` which tells you the reason for the last wakeup event.

*reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx*

[image: lastawake]